# React Navigation header title in nested tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a Tab Navigator inside a Stack Navigator and I want the header title to be dynamically configured as the title of the tab selected. Like there's 3 tabs: Home, Profile, Add Item and I want the header title to be "Home" when in the home tab, "Profile" when in the profile tab.

I tried using onStateChange on the root navigator and setOptions on the tab navigator but onStateChange is only available in the  and not in the nested navigators.

Is their anyway I can archieve this?

The navigator config is:

```
const TabNav = (
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={ProfileScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Add Item' component={AddItemScreen}/>
   </Tab.Navigator>
)

<NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='App' component={TabNav}/>
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Have you checked the official docs? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-options-resolution.html#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state

Comment: @satya164 I tried both options in the docs but neither seem to work. The route prop doesn't have `state` key

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar Navigation hierarchy with `react-navigation` v5 and I wanted to change the Header Title inside a View in the nested TabNavigator. I finally achieved it by getting the parent navigation item of the StackNavigator with `dangerouslyGetParent()` and then using `setOptions()`.

So here is your minimal Code for one of the three views inside your TabNav:

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import { useNavigation, useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {

    // TabNav navigation item
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    // Effect will be triggered everytime the Tab changes 
    //      Mounting is not enough -> Tabs will not be unmount by change
    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {

            // Get StackNav navigation item
            const stackNavigator = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
            if(stackNavigator){

                // Actually set Title
                stackNavigator.setOptions({
                    title: "Home"
                });
            }
        }, [navigation])
    );
    return (
        /* Component Items */
    );
};
```

Comment: worked for me, but only when the stack component is exactly the last parent

Comment: That's true. You need to adjust it if you have another navigation hierarchy (e.g. call dangerouslyGetParent() twice)

Comment: Thanks, life-saving answer

Answer (score 4):

From documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  // If the focused route is not found, we need to assume it's the initial screen
  // This can happen during if there hasn't been any navigation inside the screen
  // In our case, it's "Feed" as that's the first screen inside the navigator
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Feed';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Feed':
      return 'News feed';
    case 'Profile':
      return 'My profile';
    case 'Account':
      return 'My account';
  }
}

<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeTabs}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
  })}
/>
```